Unable to access the S/4 Hana Odata from the fiori app hosted in Cloud foundry BTP environment
We have deployed the Fiori app on BTP Cloud Foundry and connected it to the OData service in the public S/4HANA Cloud. The app works fine in BAS, but after hosting it on Cloud Foundry, the destination credentials are not functioning correctly in the popup.
We have created the destination using the authentication type SAMLAssertion in destination configuration. We are using xs-app.json file auth type is "xsuaa".

